# Golang reflect getting struct members in a slice

Tags: go, reflection, struct

I've the following structure:

```
type ProductionInfo struct {
StructA []struct {
    Field1            string
    Field2            int
}
```

I would extract fields name and type from StructA in the ProductionInfo type. But I cannot understand how. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the reflect package:

```
f, _ := reflect.TypeOf(ProductionInfo{}).FieldByName("StructA")
t := f.Type.Elem()
for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    f := t.Field(i)
    fmt.Println(f.Name, f.Type)
}
```

Comment: Cerise you're the man.. thank you. I was already using the reflection but didn't use the FieldByName. Many thanks